# Is always it necessary cite a reference used in a Stack Exchange question?

Tags: discussion

I found [Explicit citations and references in questions and answers on Stack Exchange websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300736).

However, it seems to me that it is not always necessary to cite a reference. For example, a math exercise you're trying to understand that has no solution in the book (or even if it does), or even quote along the lines of "<sub>*i*</sub> has a form...can be replaced by..." (a substitution rule) that one doesn't quite understand. If the context/topic is properly set, and the exercise/rule is generic enough, how does it facilitate getting a good answer by citing the text?

Comment: No, it's not always necessary. As the answer in that linked question well explains the OP themselves can be the originator of the problem asked.

Comment: It is simple.  If you are quoting someone or a source of information then you must cite them.  If you are not quoting them, and by your own brain writing the words, then well....your creating new content obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific situation - its useful for *you* because it gives context for a person trying to answer, since questions are not always complete.

On the other hand, if something's from a text book, it smacks of homework - so its worth building on that a fair bit whether or not you cite, so your question goes beyond the book, so there's no real loss citing that and other sources in your question - talk about why this approach would be better, and so on.

In a sense, its good citizenship - both in terms of crediting the source of the question, and helping people looking at the question investigate further context.